# Compile ZeroMQ with MinGW from Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, zeromq

In order to use nzmqt on Qt5 (Windows) I downloaded and compiled ZeroMQ 3.2.5 as described on GitHub. My Qt5 application compiles fine but it doesn't run: it complains about the entry point of libstdc++-6.dll.

I guess it's due to the different version of MinGW used to compile ZeroMQ (the one included in the RubyDevKit) and my application.

Thus, I'm trying to compile ZeroMQ with the MinGW which comes with Qt5... Unfortunately it's not enough to run mingw32-make from the Qt5 folders because it doesn't accept the "fail" command in the Makefile:

```
$(RECURSIVE_TARGETS):
@fail= failcom='exit 1'; \
```

This is beyond my knowledge.
I'm wondering if anyone was able to use nzmqt with ZeroMQ 3.2.5 under Windows and Qt5.

Comment: Does copying the file libstdc++-6.dll into the same folder where your .exe file is help?

Comment: I have two libstdc++-6.dll one for each MinGW (Qt5 and RubyDevKit). They are different in size. I'm afraid the application requires the one which comes with Qt5, ZeroMQ the other...

Comment: AFAIK libstdc++ isn't a library that comes with Qt5; rather it's one that is supplied by the operating system.

Comment: The Qt5 SDK contains the MinGW compiler. In its bin folder there is that library. In the same way, also the RubyDevKit contains a MinGW compiler, with its own bin folder which contains another version of libstdc++-6.dll.

Comment: Hmm, any chance to convince all parties to use MSVC instead?

Comment: FWIW under Windows I've always downloaded the Qt source archive (with Windows-style line endings) and compiled it with MSVC (using the supplied build instructions) and that's worked pretty well for me.

Comment: Ok, but for several reasons I cannot use MSVC. So I assume it's not possible to compile ZeroMQ with another version of MinGW but the RubyDevKit one.